# HTTP request has json put in string in params="" parameter, gets 400 error if intervened

Tags: python, json, http

I’m trying to modify *params* parameter of HTTP request by replacing its parts with variables. Unfortunately, it contains a string with a list in it (and that consists of dictionaries). Original parameter gets me 202 response:

```
params = (('parameters',
'[{"type":"category","target":["variable",["template-tag","user_id"]],"value":"1358216"}, \
{"type":"date/single","target":["variable",["template-tag","startDate"]],"value":"2020-03-08"},\
{"type":"date/single","target":["variable",["template-tag","endDate"]],"value":"2020-03-10"}]'),)
```

I’ve tried replacing a value of `"value"` key with a variable, but it somehow messes with quotation marks and gets me 400 response. This slightly altered code

```
user_id = "1358216"
start_date = "2020-03-08"
end_date = "2020-03-10"

pre_params = str([{"type":"category","target":["variable",["template-tag","user_id"]],"value": user_id},
                   {"type":"date/single","target":["variable",["template-tag","startDate"]],"value": start_date},
                   {"type":"date/single","target":["variable",["template-tag","endDate"]],"value": end_date}])

params = (('parameters', pre_params),)
```

transforms the string into one with a lot of backslashes — at least, debugger says so:
[part of request shown in debugger inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcjuE.png). I‘ve tried `.format()` method and f-string, both times unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to decode it to dictionary and then just modify the desired values:

```
your_values = json.load("""[
    {
        "type":"category",
        "target":["variable", ["template-tag", "user_id"]],
        "value":"1358216"
    },
    {
        "type":"date/single",
        "target":["variable", ["template-tag", "startDate"]],
        "value":"2020-03-08"
    },
    {
        "type":"date/single",
        "target":["variable", ["template-tag", "endDate"]],
        "value":"2020-03-10"
    }
]""")
```

You will get a dictionary like the one I formatted and now you can modify data with a for loop

```
user_id = "1358216"
start_date = "2020-03-08"
end_date = "2020-03-10"
for elem in your_values:
    if "user_id" in elem["target"][1]:
        elem["value"] = user_id
    if "startDate" in elem["target"][1]:
        elem["value"] = start_date
    if "endDate" in elem["target"][1]:
        elem["value"] = end_date
```

After values are modified you can dump it back to json object `new_json_obj = json.dumps(your_values)` 
if you are using django when return a HttpResponse you can specify `status=202`

Comment: Thanks, that helped! I’m gonna study json module, your answer was a boost